# Why store JS slideToggle in localStorage is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have several buttons including divs which they have the same name. unfortunately I can not change the names, they are generated by cms.

So for example when I click only on first button, only the first div is hidden or displayed, and that's fine.

But after refresh page it opens or closes all divs depending is the first div closed or opened, and that I do not want it.

And then i have created this code for testing, which works:

```
<button class="a">Button</button>
<div class="target"></div>
<button class="a">Button</button>
<div class="target"></div>

$('.a').click(function() {
  $(this).next(".target").slideToggle(function() {
    localStorage.setItem('visible-' + $(this).index(), $(this).is(":visible"));
  });
});

$.each($('.target'), function(k, trg) {
  $(trg).toggle(localStorage.getItem('visible-' + $(trg).index()) === 'true'); 
});
```

here you can see jsfiddle example: https://jsfiddle.net/pj3gs0z9/8/

and when I want to imply this method on this site: http://phpbb32.majordroid.com/index.php

for some unknown reason is not working

you need to click minus for close below, and plus to open. just try after that to refresh page, and for some reason it closes all or opens all divs below...

i have used this code:

```
$("ul.topiclist.collapse-btn").click(function(){
   $(this).parent().parent().parent().next("ul.topiclist.working-collapse-btn").trigger('click');
   $(this).toggleClass('plus');
});

$('ul.topiclist.working-collapse-btn').click(function() {
  $(this).next("ul.topiclist.forums").slideToggle(function() {
    localStorage.setItem('visible-' + $(this).index(), $(this).is(":visible"));
  });
});

$.each($('ul.topiclist.forums'), function(k, trg) {
  $(trg).toggle(localStorage.getItem('visible-' + $(trg).index()) === 'true'); 
});
```

Thank you

Comment: jsfiddle and stacksnippets will not allow localStorage due to their sandboxes

Comment: But on jsfiddle is working

Comment: I do not see it working on jsfiddle